# No puedo acceder a los datos de una tabla ManyToMany -Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, blade

Resulta que estaba intentado obtener las rutinas de un usuario, rutinas que estan asignadas en una tabla intermedia,..

**routine_user(tabla intermedia)**

```
    {
        Schema::create('routine_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('routine_id');
            $table->char('active', 1)->default('Y');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('routine_id')->references('id')->on('routines')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Modelo usuario**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User_info;
use App\Training_zone;
use App\Routine;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'subname', 'date_birth', 'email', 'password', 'gender',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    /*Declaro relaciones*/
    public function info()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User_info::class);
    }

    public function zone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Training_zone::class);
    }

    public function routines() <---- Aquí la relacion especifica, todo lo demás funciona
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Routine::class);
    }

}
```

** Modelo rutinas**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Exercise;

class Routine extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'routines';

    protected $fillable = [
        'public_name', 'technic_name', 'difficulty', 'duration', 'description',
    ];

    public function exercises()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exercise');
    }

    public function users()  <--- Que enfoca también a usuarios.
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

La lógica de esto es que yo quiero una tabla separada, dónde voy a tener a los usuarios, y las rutinas que tengan asignadas cada usuario, y para eso necesito una relación ManytoMany.

*Creo que el problema está en el controlador, ya que de alguna manera no filtro bien la query(eloquent...) y no devuelve bien lo que tendría que devolver,....*

**Controlador**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Routine;

class RoutineController extends Controller
{
    public function showUserRoutines()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user_routine = $user->routines;  <- creo que el problema radia aquí...


        return view ('panel.user-routines', compact('user', 'user_routine'));
    }
}
```

Voy a dejar la vista que estoy usando, que como podreis comprobar no me devuelve nada, me da un "Page-isn't working, pero solo en esta pagina, todas las demas funcionan correctamente...

**Vista**

```
@extends('panel.user-routines')

@section('contenido')
    @foreach($user->routines as $routine)
        <p>$routine->public_name</p>
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

Gracias, si me podéis iluminar un poco en la mejor manera para sacar los datos de las many to many lo agradecería, quiza me falle el bucle o nose.....

Si vais a decir comentarios que me mire la documentación, os lo podeis ahorrar, ya lo he hecho y no me funciona.

Comment: He arreglado lo del @extends, tenías razon, ahora me da este error: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'routines' of non-object

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ por que estaba probando a sacar los datos y no había forma, la forma ideal seria mediante $user, que ya tiene la instancia del usuario logueado, pero al hacer $user->routine no funciona

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si, con $user = Auth::user obtengo el usuario logueado, en este caso no tengo ningun middleware en el controlador, en Routes/web tampoco tengo ningún middleware, podrías enviarme el enlace de la documentación de como funciona la instanciación de laravel y esto de instanciar desde otras clases?? es que creo que me estoy haciendo un lío...... Gracias..

Comment: Acabo de hacer un dd($user); i me ha devuelto el objeto con los datos de usuario, así que diría que funciona, el problema es que me cuesta también terminar de hacer las relaciones y sacar los datos mediante eloquent....

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ al hacer {{$user->routines}} me devuelve el objeto en sí , no falla... mira  "

Comment: [{"id":1,"public_name":"Brazos marcados para verano","technic_name":"brazos-nivel-1","difficulty":"Easy","duration":"Medium","description":"Una rutina para que puedas marcar unos buenos brazos hasta verano","active":"Y","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":1,"routine_id":1}},{"id":2,"public_name":"Destroza piernas","technic_name":"piernas-nivel-extremo","difficulty":"Extreme-V","duration":"Large","description":"Esta rutina de piernas es solamente para los mas atrevidos","active":"Y","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":1,"routine_id":2}}]

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no me acaba de quedar muy claro de esto, y si por ejemplo pido los datos del campo"public_name" [{{$user->routines->public_name}}]  , me da error de instancia "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\laragon\www\Training1\resources\views\panel\user-routines.blade.php)"

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ agradecería mas un enlace donde explicasen eso, un saludo y muchas gracias por molestarte en explicar esto!!

Comment: Puedes leer en la documentación lo relativo a Eloquent: Relación [Muchos a Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) y para obtener los datos, te servirá [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: Estaría bueno que edites la pregunta para poder responderla, agregando lo que dices en los comentarios, así es mas fácil de leer. Leíste la respuesta que ya tiene? O si encontraste la solución y quieres compartirla en una respuesta también

Comment: No la he resuelto aún, sigue así :/

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria algo así la solución:

```
relacion
public function routines(){
  return $this->hasMany(Routine::class, 'routine_id','id')->select('routine_id','public_name');
}

$user= User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
->first()
->with('routines')
->get();
```